# Is there a neat way to pop a page and schedule a callback to be called after navigation is complete?

Tags: flutter, navigator

I want to call `Navigator.of(context).pop()` one or several times and then run a callback after navigation has completed, but I have struggled to find a neat solution.  I've put together an example app to illustrate the problem I'm having:

- Screens A, B, and C all access a nullable `value` on the `Model` Provider
- `ScreenA` can set `value` to a non-null value
- `ScreenB` requires `value` to be non-null to build
- `ScreenC` can set `value` to null and pop you back to `ScreenA`

When you press the button on `ScreenC` to go back to `ScreenA`, it navigates successfully (the app doesn't crash) but you throw an `Error` because it tries to build `ScreenB` after the first pop.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => Model(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const ScreenA(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Model extends ChangeNotifier {
  int? value = 0;

  Future<void> updateValue(int? newValue) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 30));
    value = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: centredScreenContent(
        [
          Text('ScreenA - value: ${context.watch<Model>().value}'),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Set value'),
            onPressed: () => context.read<Model>().updateValue(Random().nextInt(100)),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Go to B'),
            onPressed: () async => await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => ScreenB(
                  nonNullValue: context.watch<Model>().value ?? (throw Error()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenB({Key? key, required this.nonNullValue}) : super(key: key);
  final int nonNullValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: centredScreenContent(
        [
          Text('ScreenB - value: $nonNullValue'),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Set value'),
            onPressed: () => context.read<Model>().updateValue(Random().nextInt(100)),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Go to C'),
            onPressed: () async => await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const ScreenC(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenC extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenC({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: centredScreenContent(
        [
          const Spacer(),
          const Text('ScreenC'),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                context.read<Model>().updateValue(null);
              },
              child: const Text('Reset app')),
          const Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget centredScreenContent(List<Widget> widgets) => Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: widgets,
      ),
    );
```

I've found two solutions, but neither feels neat:

1. Make `ScreenB` take a nullable value in its constructor, and have its build return something like `value == null ? Container() : ActualContents(nonNullValue: value!)`. I don't like this though. If we know that in BAU use, `ScreenB` cannot be built while `value == null`, then we'd like to log an error if that happens in production so we can investigate the problem. We can't do this if our navigation back from `ScreenC` also hits this state though.
2. Add a sufficiently long delay to the callback so that it runs after the navigation is completed, e.g. in the example app, if you change `Model.updateValue` to have a 300ms delay, then it doesn't error. This also feels like an unpleasant solution, if the delay is too long we risk the app behaving sluggishly, if it's too short then we don't solve the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would make `ScreenB(int? nullableParam)` and handle the widget builder with additional `assert nullableParam == null` just to log the error.

But what i think the real solution you are looking for is `context.read<Model>().value` instead of `watch` - i can't think of a scenario where you want to page parameter depend on any listenable state

#### solution

```
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Go to B'),
            onPressed: () async => await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => ScreenB(
                  nonNullValue: context.read<Model>().value ?? (throw Error()),
```

This way the page after first build will not be rebuild with null when popped.

@Edit

I see 2 problems:

- passing Listenable value to Page parameter
- purposely setting value to null where other part of application purposely is not handling it

The first one can be solved with the `solution` above

The second you have to either assure the passed value will not be null on `Navigator.pop()` - `the solution` above does that. Or handle the null value in the ScreenB widget (as you suggested with conditional build)

Comment: This does stop the error, but is limiting. e.g. in the example app `ScreenB` has a button that changes `Model.value`. If you use `context.watch<Model>().value` then the UI in `ScreenB` updates with the new value. If you use `context.read<Model>().value` then the UI does not update.

Comment: What is the reason for passing the value to `ScreenB`? you can `context.watch<Model>().value` directly from the `build()` of the `ScreenB`

The `parameter` passed into the Routes should be used as a Route parameter and not passing values around

Comment: In this little example app you can do that. In a less contrived app, `ScreenB` may be a reusable component that I wish to use elsewhere in the app where the integer passed into it comes from something else.

Comment: I don't think that's an important point though, if you do `final int nonNullValue = context.watch<Model>().value ?? (throw Error());` in `ScreenB.build` instead of passing it in through `ScreenB`'s constructor, you still get the same error thrown.